# What is experimental in this Node snippet that reads a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was running code from here:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });
  // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
  // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.

  for await (const line of rl) {
    // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
    console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
  }
}

processLineByLine();
```

and got this warning:

```
(node:13735) ExperimentalWarning: readline Interface [Symbol.asyncIterator] is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(node:13735) ExperimentalWarning: Readable[Symbol.asyncIterator] is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
```

What is experimental exactly?  There is no line number.

Answer (score -1):

It says:

> readline Interface [Symbol.asyncIterator]

So look for an interface:

> ```
> const rl = readline.createInterface
> ```

that you are iterating over:

> ```
> const line of rl
> ```